# login against ldap server

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

i have a php login page using ldap, it works fine if the login is good(redirect to mainpage) and bad ( error message appears), but it also redirect me to the mainpage if i write any username without password. How can i correct it?

Also i am not sure if the use of session_start is correct.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){?>



<?

$adServer = "ldap://server.domain.local";

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$ldaprdn = 'Domain' . "\\" . $username;

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);


if ($bind) {
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"ou=country,dc=domain,dc=local",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);        
    session_start();               
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     header("Location: /main.php");
     @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    /**$msg = "Invalid email address / password";
    echo $msg;*/

    echo "<center><h2>Failed authentication for <span style='color: #000;'>" . $username     . "</span><br /><br />
              <a href='login.php'>Try again</a></center>";

}

}else{
?>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This isn't exactly a perfect answer to your question -- but using LDAP is awful. I'd much rather interact with login via HTTPS. There's a company you can use to do this (they'll translate HTTPS -> LDAP for you): https://stormpath.com

Comment: Thanks, but we are only going to use as a simple intranet page for use in the office.